# Modify sphider search.php file and help me please

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm in trouble with search.php file of sphider website indexing and search script. I need your help. 
   Actually i want to put sphider search script in my website to search the pages with keywords. But i have a problem. i have attached a search box in each page of website and now i want to put search.php file of sphider in form action. But when i checked i got that it don;t search results but beside it shows a search box in search.php file and when i enter any keyword and hit enter then it shows the results. So my question is. How to remove this search box from this search.php file and only get the search result.

' search.php?query= [---Here comes the search keywords entered in box--]  &search=1'

this is URL that shows after hitting enter from search.php search box but when putting all details right in my page search engine it doesn't do anything and only ask to search through that box... So guys please help me....

```html
<?php
/*******************************************
* Sphider Version 1.3.x
* This program is licensed under the GNU GPL.
* By Ando Saabas          ando(a t)cs.ioc.ee
********************************************/
//error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_WARNING); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
$include_dir = "./include"; 
include ("$include_dir/commonfuncs.php");
//extract(getHttpVars());

if (isset($_GET['query']))
 $query = $_GET['query'];
if (isset($_GET['search']))
 $search = $_GET['search'];
if (isset($_GET['domain'])) 
 $domain = $_GET['domain'];
if (isset($_GET['type'])) 
 $type = $_GET['type'];
if (isset($_GET['catid'])) 
 $catid = $_GET['catid'];
if (isset($_GET['category'])) 
 $category = $_GET['category'];
if (isset($_GET['results'])) 
 $results = $_GET['results'];
if (isset($_GET['start'])) 
 $start = $_GET['start'];
if (isset($_GET['adv'])) 
 $adv = $_GET['adv'];
 
 
$include_dir = "./include"; 
$template_dir = "./templates"; 
$settings_dir = "./settings"; 
$language_dir = "./languages";


require_once("$settings_dir/database.php");
require_once("$language_dir/en-language.php");
require_once("$include_dir/searchfuncs.php");
require_once("$include_dir/categoryfuncs.php");


include "$settings_dir/conf.php";

include "$template_dir/$template/header.html";
include "$language_dir/$language-language.php";


if ($type != "or" && $type != "and" && $type != "phrase") { 
 $type = "and";
}

if (preg_match("/[^a-z0-9-.]+/", $domain)) {
 $domain="";
}


if ($results != "") {
 $results_per_page = $results;
}

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()==1) {
 $query = stripslashes($query);
} 

if (!is_numeric($catid)) {
 $catid = "";
}

if (!is_numeric($category)) {
 $category = "";
} 



if ($catid && is_numeric($catid)) {

 $tpl_['category'] = sql_fetch_all('SELECT category FROM '.$mysql_table_prefix.'categories WHERE category_id='.(int)$_REQUEST['catid']);
}
 
$count_level0 = sql_fetch_all('SELECT count(*) FROM '.$mysql_table_prefix.'categories WHERE parent_num=0');
$has_categories = 0;

if ($count_level0) {
 $has_categories = $count_level0[0][0];
}



require_once("$template_dir/$template/search_form.html");


function getmicrotime(){
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ",microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
    }



function poweredby () {
 global $sph_messages;
    //If you want to remove this, please donate to the project at http://www.sphider.eu/donate.php
    print $sph_messages['Powered by'];?>  <a href="http://www.sphider.eu/"><img src="sphider-logo.png" border="0" style="vertical-align: middle" alt="Sphider"></a>

    <?php 
}


function saveToLog ($query, $elapsed, $results) {
        global $mysql_table_prefix;
    if ($results =="") {
        $results = 0;
    }
    $query =  "insert into ".$mysql_table_prefix."query_log (query, time, elapsed, results) values ('$query', now(), '$elapsed', '$results')";
 mysql_query($query);
                    
 echo mysql_error();
                        
}

switch ($search) {
 case 1:

  if (!isset($results)) {
   $results = "";
  }
  $search_results = get_search_results($query, $start, $category, $type, $results, $domain);
  require("$template_dir/$template/search_results.html");
 break;
 default:
  if ($show_categories) {
   if ($_REQUEST['catid']  && is_numeric($catid)) {
    $cat_info = get_category_info($catid);
   } else {
    $cat_info = get_categories_view();
   }
   require("$template_dir/$template/categories.html");
  }
 break;
 }

include "$template_dir/$template/footer.html";
?>
 //*

 I have removed 
require_once("$template_dir/$template/search_form.html");
 and checked whether it work. But no it didn't work. So i'm getting frustrated.. 
 Somebody please help me..
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line:

```
$search_results = get_search_results($query, $start, $category, $type, $results, $domain);
```

This is a function being called from a file that is included above `searchfuncs.php` I you want to use the Sphider search functionality with your own search bar do the following (assuming MVC pattern is used):

1. Include `searchfunc.php` in your controller for your searchbar
2. Format your keywords from the searchbar to fit conventions for Sphider and prepare the required parameters for step #3
3. Call the `get_search_results()` function from your custom controller
4. Now that you are getting results you may want to create a custom view to handle the search results, or else refer back to `sphider/templates/standard/search_results.html` for the required HTML for default Sphider results.